# Getting return value from stored procedure dynamically in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am using 2 stored procedures in Execute SQL Task in SSIS in a ForEach loop container. From 1st procedure i am returning the value as scope_identity which i want to access in 2nd stored procedure dynamically.Below are the stored procedures. First stored procedure :-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertTm]
      @filename nvarchar(128),
      @date date,
      @count int,
      @fileid int output
AS
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TmRecruitment(FileName,FileLoadDate,RecordCount)
      VALUES (@filename, @date, @count)
      SET @fileid=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      RETURN  @fileid
END
I have created appropriate variables and mapped 3 variables as input and 1 variable as output variable to recieve the value of scope identity.
Second stored procedure is :-


ALTER proc [dbo].[toinsertTx]
    (@fileido int)
    as
    begin
    insert into TxRecruitment
    (JobReqID,TemplateName,JobType,JobLevel,JobTitle,HeadcountType,Backfill,RequisitionStatus,Status,CurrentApprover,Department,SubDepartment
    ,CostCenterID,Country,JobPostingLocation,DepartmentHead,SubDeptHead,HiringManager,BudgetController,Recruiter,DateCreated,ApprovedDate   
    ,Age,TimeToReqApproval,NoOfDaysOpen)
    select * from TsRecruitment

    update TxRecruitment set FileId=@fileido
    end
```

All things I am getting correctly and i am taking the value of scope identity into variable @fileido. I have 3 files and i want scope identity to return the value of FileId each time it is getting one file. But i am getting the return value only one as 3. But i want value to be returned as 1 then 2 and then 3.
What should be the right way to do this so that i get the return value differntly each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for each loop container which has two execute sql tasks inside it,first for [dbo].[insertTm] and second for [dbo].[toinsertTx] respectively.You can use For each loop for ADO enumerator if the file name and other input details for [dbo].[insertTm] picked up from a table, if the file name and other details are picked from files, use a file enumerator.  This would keep updating the input variables for [dbo].[insertTm] and the output of this SP which has the current scope identity can be fetched and passed to the second SP.

Comment: i have used a ForEach loop container and file enumerator. The value of scope identity is not being fetched one by one but at once,it seems. Scope identity is returning only one value i.e 3 which is the last value of identity. It is not returning value dynamically i.e after each file returning different value of identity like 1 for 1st file,2 foe second and 3 for last file.

Comment: Are you also using two execute tasks for the SPs inside the loop itself?

Comment: yes, in the for each i am using 1st execute task for 1st sp i.e toinsertTm and 2nd for toinsertTx sp

Comment: i have mapped 3 variable as input and 1 variable as output in 1st sp and i am using the output variable of 1st sp as input variable for 2nd sp. Only problem is that i am getting value as 3 for the entire column of FileId but i want it as 1 for 1st, 2 for second and 3 for third. I have not used result set for 1st procedure...is that a problem?

Comment: I hope there is no error in second sp,you are using an update statement i.e. update TxRecruitment set FileId=@fileido , which will ultimately map all the fileid to 3 as the final loop will have the @fileido value as 3.

Comment: What part needs to be improved or changed for correct solution...please tell..@kapil

Comment: View the variable value at run time by setting up debugging and breakpoint.Refer this for viewing runtime variable value

http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-watch-value-of-variables.html

If the @fileido value is changing everytime ,you can be assured that the scope_identity() is returning correct value.

In that case , you might have to check if the Update query in your second SP has to be corrected as it is updating the entire row of fileid to the latest fileid.That is ,if your last loop had updated the fileid field to 2, next one will update the entire field to 3.

Comment: For inserting only the latest fileid,go for below insert statement

 
Insert into TxRecruitment
    (Fileid,JobReqID,TemplateName,JobType,JobLevel,JobTitle,HeadcountType,Backfill,RequisitionStatus,Status,CurrentApprover,Department,SubDepartment
    ,CostCenterID,Country,JobPostingLocation,DepartmentHead,SubDeptHead,HiringManager,BudgetController,Recruiter,DateCreated,ApprovedDate   
    ,Age,TimeToReqApproval,NoOfDaysOpen)
    select  @fileido,* from TsRecruitment

Comment: I changed the sp as you said and I got it correctly. thanks a lot man..you have been such a great help. Thanks @kapil

Comment: Glad to help :)